# Does anybody know of a site that has a set of all theorems?

Tags: reference-request

I mean, if there exists a site that his function is to show and save theorems with their proofs?

Comment: http://planetmath.org/

Comment: _All_ theorems is a tall order. You might be interested in [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/) perhaps?

Comment: I mean not all, but a lot of them. Yes that is Im looking for. Thanks @DylanMoreland

Comment: @DylanMoreland, i thinks that U need your comment like answer. For i can put like this is the answer i needed. :)

Comment: What about sites corresponding to the automated proof-checkers?

Comment: This reminds me of "The Book" of Erdos, only less elegant.

Comment: Hey, nobody brought up [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) and [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/), yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short list -- although it is indeed impossible to list all theorems.

- [Planetmath](http://planetmath.org/)
- [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_theorems)
- [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/)

Feel free to add any website/reference you find!